# Rethinkdb - Get first item of an array

Tags: rethinkdb

My data structure

```
    {
      "group": "fruits"
      "items": ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
    }
```

I need to pull first item from the "items" array without knowing the value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer. I can use "nth(0)" to get item at index 0.